# Build framework for multiple architectures (arm64, armv7, armv7s)

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks

I'm trying to upload to TestFlight a project build for arm64, armv7, and armv7s. It is using a framework from another project. But the frameowork appears to be built only for arm64 and not arm64 (`file was built for arm64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)`).

The question is how do I make the framework containing all architectures? I want to keep the projects separated. And I don't care for simulators. I want to make sure it is built for release.

This is the framework target:

[image]

**EDIT:** My project is Cordova based. So it is using a plugin which utilize a pre-built framework. There are instructions out there for building a fat framework, containing simulators and device, then concatenating it with `lipo`. What I need is the architecture from the device I don't have as well. Does that actually mean I need three devices from arm64, armv7, and armv7s to be able to concatenating them altogether?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apple has discontinued support for 32-bit in iOS 11. You can neither run 32 bit apps on iOS 11 nor run iOS 11 on 32 bit processors. Thus, you have to set your *Deployment Target* to an iOS version earlier than iOS 11 for your framework.

Comment: Whah! You were right that was what was missing. TestFlight accepted the binary. Thank you so much!

Comment: Brilliant! Saved me time  for sure. Just a typo - it should be _Deployment Target_

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for this answer. I've been stuck with a similar issue, and after trying dozens of different solutions over the course of ~8 hours, this is what worked. I usually never post on StackOverflow but just wanted to express my appreciation for this. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create an aggregate target and write an script which will support all the platform. This is sample script from one of my project.

```
unset TOOLCHAINS #Xcode 7.3 BUG FIX  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184930/xcodebuild-7-3-cant-enable-bitcode

# define output folder environment variable

C_PROJECT_NAME="<<YOUR_FRAMEWORK_NAME>>"

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target <<YOUR_FRAMEWORK_NAME>> ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

xcodebuild -target <<YOUR_FRAMEWORK_NAME>> ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 -arch x86_64 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

rm -rf ./${C_PROJECT_NAME}.framework
cp -R ${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}${EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME}/${C_PROJECT_NAME}.framework ./

# Step 2. Create universal binary file using lipo

lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${C_PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${C_PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${C_PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${C_PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${C_PROJECT_NAME}"

mv ${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${C_PROJECT_NAME} ./${C_PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${C_PROJECT_NAME}
```